# How to get x to always eventually equal y by adding steps of 24

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a python Script and I have two variables

count or x which 4991

and toWhat or y which is 1199.

These values will change, but when they do change, I need to make sure that y will eventually equal x if you add +24 to y after a iteration of while loop.

How can I create a function that will check the values of x and y to make sure this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract y from x, then divide the result by 24. If there is no remainder then they will be equal at some point.

(x - y) % 24 = 0

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple, just was having a serious brain fart about how to do it.